# mysqli bind_param - variable scope issues?

Tags: php, session, mysqli, global

I have a php include file, function.php with the following code snippet:

```
function check_login($mysqli) {
   // Check if all session variables are set
   if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'])) {
     $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];// current value will be 9
     $username = $_SESSION['username'];


     if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        //
        //
        //
        return true;
     }
   }
}
```

In another file, test.php, I execute

```
if(check_login($mysqli) == true) //......
```

And then further down in test.php, I set the value of the variable $user_id

```
$user_id = "5";
```

So now the problem, is that since $user_id was already defined in my functions.php file as the value of the session's user_id, it overrides the actual session data.

It's almost like $user_id in test.php is treating the variable as a global one, which causes the session's user_id to also change.

Why does this happen?

Comment: If I understand you right... You're setting $user_id inside your function; that is setting a local variable in the function, called $user_id. If you're not returning that from your function - and I assume you're not, given the `return true` at the end - then the value is being lost. When you set the value in test.php, of course it's going to overwrite it - it doesn't matter how you're setting it elsewhere; if you explicitly set the value to 5, then any earlier value will be overwritten.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. I just don't understand why creating another variable, outside the check_login() function, could modify the value within the check_login() function itself. Because when this happens, it actually changes the session's user_id value. That's the part I don't understand. I do set it to 5, however, shouldn't the variable for $user_id, within the check_login() function, not be able to be changed (since it's not defined globally)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you assign a value to `$user_id`, it shouldn't have any effect on the session; that should only happen if you explicitly change the value in the session.

Comment: Effectively, you've got three different variables. `$user_id` inside your function is set there; and when the function returns, it disappears. `$user_id` outside the function is a completely separate variable, which happens to have the same name. Setting either of these will not affect what happens to the other. Finally, `$_SESSION['user_id']` is a third variable; you can set it in the same way (and it is in scope everywhere, so setting it inside a function will affect it everywhere). But if assign its value to `$user_id`, then changing `$user_id` won't affect the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I finally figured it out. Register_globals was set to on. Doh!